# Is it possible to differentiate $\sin x$ with respect to $\cos x$ from first principles?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, chain-rule

I was doing a practice problem today for a University admissions test, where it asked me to differentiate $\sin x$ with respect to $\cos x$. The solution I found used the chain rule:

\begin{align}
\frac{d\sin x}{d\cos x}&=\frac{d\sin x}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{d\cos x} \\
&=\cos x\cdot\frac{1}{-\sin x} \\
&=-\cot x
\end{align}

However, the more I thought about this problem, the more it made me a feel a little uncomfortable. I don't really understand what it means to differentiate a function with respect to another function, if that is even possible. So I tried to differentiate $\sin x$ with respect to $\cos x$ from first principles, just so I knew what I was working with:

$$
\frac{d\sin x}{d\cos x}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\sin (\cos x+h)-\sin(\cos x)}{h}
$$

The idea behind this was to treat $\cos x$ just as I would any other variable. However, this gave me the incorrect answer of $(\cos \circ \cos)(x)$, and I can't understand why. Is there an intuitive way of thinking about what it means to differentiate a function with respect to another function?

Comment: Since $\sin^2(x)+\cos(x)^2=1$ we have $2\sin(x) \frac {d\sin(x)}{d\cos(x)}+2\cos (x)=0$ so..

Comment: Seems a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3791759/65203

Comment: @YvesDaoust The question you linked to has since been deleted, but if it was the one titled 'HELP ME IN DOING THIS QUESTION', then that post was an identical copy to this one, and it was posted a few minutes later. I have no idea why someone would do that.

Comment: @JoeLamond: ask Pvitaar Bachha.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I suppose I'll give them the benefit of the doubt, given that they were completely new to the site. At least they received the Peer Pressure badge :)

Comment: @JoeLamond: does your life depend on it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to measure a change in $\sin{x}$ with respect to a change in $\cos{x}$. So you want $\sin{x}$ as a function of $\cos{x}$, which is not the same thing as $\sin(\cos{x})$. Therein is your fundamental issue.

What you want: if $x \in [0, \pi]$, then $\sin{x} = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2{x}}$, and so
\begin{align*} \frac{d(\sin{x})}{d(\cos{x})} &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{1 - (\cos{x} + h)^2} - \sqrt{1 - \cos^2{x}}}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{[1 - (\cos{x} + h)^2] - (1 - \cos^2{x})}{h(\sqrt{1 - (\cos x + h)^2} + \sqrt{1 - \cos^2{x}})} \\
&= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{-h(h + 2\cos{x})}{h(\sqrt{1 - (\cos x + h)^2} + \sqrt{1 - \cos^2{x}})} \\
&= \frac{-2\cos{x}}{2\sqrt{1 - \cos^2{x}}} = -\frac{\cos{x}}{\sin{x}} = -\cot{x} \end{align*}
as desired.

Exercise: what happens when $x \in [\pi, 2\pi]$?

Comment: It took me sometime to notice that you have written $\cos x+h$ instead of $\cos(x+h) $ and I hope readers can understand why it is done that way. +1

Answer (score 1):

Set $y=\cos x$, then, for $x\in[0,\pi]$,
$$
\frac{d\sin x}{d\cos x}=\left.\frac{d\sin(\arccos y)}{dy}\right|_{y=\cos x}=-\left.\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}\right|_{y=\cos x}=-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}=-\cot x,
$$
As for the limit, you should write
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(\arccos(y+h)-\sin(\arccos(y))}{h}=\\
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\sin(\arccos(\cos x+h)-\sin x}{h}.
$$